# Will I need visa for my international transfer at Milan Malpensa Airport?

Tags: schengen, transit, schengen-visas, transit-visas, milan

I am flying from Istanbul to São Paulo, the transfer is on my responsibility, these 2 flights are 2 different airlines however both my arrival and departure must be non Schengen Zone, International transit zone.I do have only cabin luggage with me. I hold Turkish Passport, I have contacted with the embassy and they told me that I will not need visa since the time between my flights are 2.5h- I have seen one of the online forums that states MXP(Milan Malpensa) does not have international transit zone, is it even possible? Both of my flights are arriving to and leaving from Terminal 1. I contacted to Turkish Airlines my first flight, they said they don’t know either. Anyone had any similar experiences? Thanks

Comment: The problem is that even if you could do an airside sterile transit, the first airline will likely consider that your final destination is Italy and ask for the relevant paperwork to enter Italy. You are likely to not be allowed to board the first flight at all. Some airlines will accept evidence of the other ticket, some won’t, it’s quite difficult to predict.

Comment: That was also one of my other concern, I have contacted them via phone and they stated it must be no problem but I can’t predict the individuals in the onboarding. I will get from them written confirmation email. However if anyone knows is there an international transit zone in Milan Malpesa Airport? Do I supposed to pass the passport control for my flight to São Paulo at the airport?

Comment: [Timatic seems to think it’s possible to do an airside transit in MXP](https://www.emirates.com/fr/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=tr&destination=br&transit=it) as long as you don’t have to change terminals. I personally don’t know the current layout of the airport, though.

Comment: Using made-up flight and passport expiration dates, [Skyteam.Traveldoc](https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/) (another reputable source) also returns that this itinerary is OK without a Schengen visa for the Malpensa transit.